# Running Selenium without having any browser

Tags: python, selenium

I want to run a Selenium script on a remote server. I am using Chrome as the browser, but there is no Chrome (or any other browser) on the server. I know I can use headless mode so it doesn't physically open a browser, but would that option work if there isn't actually any browser (the server does have internet connectivity)?

I was also looking at Selenium remote webdriver. For that, would I have to install the selenium server on a server that actually does have Chrome browser and then point it to that server?

In other words, I have a Selenium test script that I run locally (where I do have Chrome browser). Is it possible run this on a server that doesn't have any browsers? I am trying to centralize this so that anyone on my team can run the script by creating a job out of it. Right now it is only local.

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit on why you are in this situation, perhaps people here can help with something that might not have crossed your mind. Your scenario is a bit unclear. What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve. Why the need to run this on the server etc.

Comment: Might sound a bit off key but why not install chrome on the server?  Surely that's the easy answer? The SeleniumHQ page says selenium "enable and support the automation of web browsers."... So you kinda need a Web browser if you want to use selenium . As alternatives, if you can't install it, you can consider the selenium Docker examples or zalenium. They'll give your a browser in a container but you'll still need to rewrite your script to use the remote browser.